# receive null value SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqflite

I create the following function to calculate total between two dates but always get null value what was wrong ?

```
void calcul_total_period() async {

  var totalSumPeriod = (await databaseHelper.claculTotalPeriod(startDate, endDate))[0]['TOTAL'];  //['$startDate''$endDate'];
  print(' $totalSumPeriod');
  setState(() {
    somme_period = totalSumPeriod ?? 00;
    somme_total_period = somme.toStringAsFixed(2);
  });
}
```

function in db

```
 Future claculTotalPeriod (String startDate, String endDate) async {
    var totalClientperiod = await database;
    var result = await totalClientperiod.rawQuery("SELECT SUM($colPrix) AS TOTAL from $clientTable WHERE $colDate BETWEEN '$startDate' AND '$endDate'");
    print('$result');
    return result.toList();
  }
```

Comment: You should tag this with the language in your pasted code. This doesn't look like SQL at all.

Comment: I think it worth to check result before getting a [0] and then before getting a ['TOTAL'] to ensure result contains such key

Answer (score 0):

What's **somme** ?

```
void calcul_total_period() async {

  var totalSumPeriod = (await databaseHelper.claculTotalPeriod(startDate, endDate))[0]['TOTAL'];  //['$startDate''$endDate'];
  print(' $totalSumPeriod');
  setState(() {
    somme_period = totalSumPeriod ?? 00;
    somme_total_period = ---> somme <----.toStringAsFixed(2);
  });
}
```